# Can't find fragment by id or tag....yet it is there

Tags: android, android-fragments

My main activity has a button and a fragment (note the button's onclick event is assigned here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="184dp"
        android:text="Button"
        android:onClick="onButtonClicked"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment"
        android:name="com.example.steve.fragmentdemo.MyFragment"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="159dp" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

The fragment has a textview, an id and a tag:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    tools:context=".MyFragment"
    android:id="@+id/myFragmentId"
    android:tag="myFragmentTag"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/myTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Soon to be overwritten" />

</FrameLayout>
```

The fragment has a public function to write to the text view:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    public MyFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my, container, false);
    }

    public void  setText(String theText){
        TextView text = getView().findViewById(R.id.myTextView);

        text.setText(theText);
    }
}
```

The main activity can get to the fragment but only through the list of fragments!

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void onButtonClicked(View view)
    {
        FragmentManager supportFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

        MyFragment frameLayout;

        frameLayout = (MyFragment)supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.myFragmentId);
        // Nope find by ID failed

        frameLayout = (MyFragment)supportFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("myFragmentTag");
        // Nope find by tag failed

        List<Fragment> myList = supportFragmentManager.getFragments();

        frameLayout = (MyFragment)myList.get(0);

        //  And yet, the fragment is in the list of fragments
        if (frameLayout != null)
            frameLayout.setText("Hi There");   // this worked!
    }
}
```

What gives?

FYI:  I'm a seasoned developer and I'm learning Android for fun...how sick is that?

Comment: Your `Fragment`'s ID is `fragment`, not `myFragmentId`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your id here should be the layout that holds the fragments instead of one actual fragment. Thus, the real id should be "fragment".

Comment: Ah, it is the id assigned in the containing object.    That also clears up how you can have several copies of the same fragment in one container.